# Is it possible to set rootMetricsPrefix with a command line parameter?

Tags: jmeter

My JMeter test receives a parameter to specify test environment like PROD, DEV.

Results from both test environment will be sent to a certain GraphiteHost. But I need to separate the results of each environment by using `rootMetricsPrefix`.

For example, results from PROD will use prefix `global.myapp.performance.prod.` while the results from DEV will use prefix `global.myapp.performance.dev.`.

So I set the `rootMetricsPrefix` in my Backend Listener as `global.myapp.performance.${__groovy($__P(env).toLowerCase())}.`.
Unfortunately, It doesn't work.

Data in Graphite doesn't contains the environment name.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK I tried both answers but it didn’t work. I will try again tomorrow and let you know the result.

Comment: I tried them both on my side and the correct text is generated so I think they both work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your expression it should be:

> global.myapp.performance.${__groovy("${__P(env)}".toLowerCase())}

This will also work:

> global.myapp.performance.${__groovy(props.get("env").toLowerCase())}

But for performances, it is better to use the solution provided by @user7294900

Comment: Thanks. Both of them work well. I choose this one as an answer because it tells me about the mistake.

Comment: Yes, the other answer is also correct and probably better for performances, but I wanted to show indeed what was the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use new [changeCase](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__changeCase) function to lower case your value:

```
${__changeCase(${__P(env)},LOWER,)}
```

It will read the property and then execute lower case on value